# Using JavaScript to set the height and width of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the height and width of a div through javascript and to no avail. I have tried numerous things and had no luck so far please advise me where i am going wrong? I thought this would just be straight forward...

I am not sure what the problem is here, I cannot use CSS in this case to set the variables i need to do it in JavaScript that is another topic all together though.

```
<div id="demo">Demo Div</div>

<script>
    var test = document.getElementById("demo");
    test.style.width = "100px";
    test.style.height = "100px";
    test.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.(I am open to a jQuery alternative as well)

-Epik-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your last line is setting `cssText`, which overwrites the styles set on the first two lines rather than adding to them. Try this instead:

```
var test = document.getElementById("demo");
test.style.width = "100px";
test.style.height = "100px";
test.style.border = '1px solid black'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtyfB/

And since you mentioned jQuery, here's one way you could use it to do the same thing:

```
$("#demo").css({
    width : "100px",
    height : "100px",
    border : '1px solid black'
});
```

Comment: ahh thank you for that nice, simple and fast reply awesome work there!

Answer (score 0):

**The `cssText` is overwriting the height and width you set, as well as any other styling you had.**

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/), thanks to [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn):

```
$("#demo").css({
    width : "100px",
    height : "100px",
    border : '1px solid black'
});
```

---

I would recommend trashing `cssText` for `border` like so:

```
var test = document.getElementById("demo");
test.style.border = '1px solid black';
test.style.width = "100px";
test.style.height = "100px";
```

But if you really need `cssText`, then use it first:

```
var test = document.getElementById("demo");
test.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;';
test.style.width = "100px";
test.style.height = "100px";
```

The last viable solution is to do it all using `cssText`:

```
var test = document.getElementById("demo");
test.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px';
```